# How do I run Chrome through Appium (v2) on a windows machine ("No matching capabilities found")

Tags: webdriver, appium, chromium

I want to run tests on a remote Windows 10 machine.
The machine has Chrome installed.

I installed Appium and the chromium driver in a simple npm package on that machine.

`package.json`

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "appium": "^2.5.1",
    "appium-chromium-driver": "^1.3.20"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "appium --allow-cors"
  }
}
```

then I start Appium like this:

> npm run start

I Test the Server locally using the Appium Inspector (https://inspector.appiumpro.com/):

```
Remote Host: 127.0.0.1
Remote Port: 4723
Remote Path: /
```

```json
{
  "platformName": "Windows",
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "appium:automationName": "Chromium"
}
```

When I click `Start Session`, I get this Error:

`Failed to create session. An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: A new session could not be created. Details: session not created: No matching capabilities found`

I don't know what to do.

Most resources, blog posts and questions refer to the outdated Appium V1.

What am I doing wrong?
Is it odd to try that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The problem is that the `platformName` must be lowercase `windows`.

[I issued a bug](https://github.com/appium/appium-chromium-driver/issues/284), since this is a documentation issue.